# Compare two datasets to find the rows that are not present in one of the datset in r

Tags: r

I have two datasets, the Ids in the datasets are unordered and there are multiple values which are present in one dataset but not in the other dataset.

What I want at the end is csv file which contains the non-common Ids of both the dataset columns.

```
Dataset 1
Id Quant
1     a
2     b
3     c
4     d
5     e
6     f
7     g

Dataset 2
Id Quant2
6     d
4     a
5     f
2     e
1     a
3     b
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `dplyr` package which has a `anti_join` function for precisely this task:

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(dataset1, dataset2, by = "Id")
```

This will return all rows of `dataset1` where there is no matching `Id` in `dataset2`. Similarly you can take a look at

```
 anti_join(dataset2, dataset1, by = "Id")
```